# Identifying open and closed server IP Address/ports

Tags: wget

I use a fairly simple WGET command to verify if the IP Address and port are open or closed for a particular server: `wget -a /tmp/ports.log -t1 -T1 10.178.30.45:443`

The issue I have is that there are a number of servers that I need to check, and each server links to other IP addresses/ports.

Currently I have several of these one liner type scripts deployed on each of the specific servers which require being run manually as and when required.

Ideally, I am looking to customize this with one script that can recursively read in a flat file of IP addresses/ports using a WGET command. The resulting report produced will identify those that are not connected (ie: "failed: Connection timed out.").

The script should ideally run from within windows rather than deployed and run on each of the server.  A list of user id’s/passwords can be obtained for each server if this needs to be passed via the script.

Comment: On windows? You're asking on a *nix forum for a solution that can run on windows? Of course `wget` is cross platform, but the suggestions for scripting you are going to get here are going to be *nix central!

Comment: @Caleb: [It's ok to ask about unix-y tools even if you're running on them other platforms.](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436/cygwin-on-topic) @Evan: But you should be clear about what you're using. In particular, it's not clear what unix scripting tool you expect to be available (in addition to wget): Cygwin? Any POSIX shell and utilities?

Answer (score 6):

The network scanning app [`nmap`](http://nmap.org/) would be a much more apt tool to scan a batch of IPs to figure out if the host is up and if a particular port is open.

Answer (score 5):

As [suggested by Caleb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11756/identifying-open-and-closed-server-ip-address-ports/11762#11762), `nmap` should be the tool of choice in this case. With `nmap` you can do like this:

```
nmap  127.0.0.1 -p 80,21-25
```

to learn whether one or more ports (in this example port #s 21-25, and 80) are open or closed on a particular IP address. In my machine I get the following output:

```
Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-04-21 15:29 IST
Interesting ports on localhost (127.0.0.1):
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
25/tcp closed smtp
26/tcp closed rsftp
27/tcp closed nsw-fe
28/tcp closed unknown
29/tcp closed msg-icp
80/tcp open   http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.12 seconds
```

Nmap for Windows can be [downloaded from here](http://nmap.org/download.html).